# Using getopt() to find targets

Tags: c, makefile, posix

So I know you can use `getopt()` to find option arguments, but what about other things in the argv array such as targets? Is there a way to do this using `getopt()`? Looking through the man page and I don't see anything... maybe I'm missing it.

Comment: What are targets in `argv` ? Perhaps consider (on Linux) the [argp functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argp.html)

Comment: Can you elaborate what you my "targets"?

Comment: I've explained in my comment below the first answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `optarg` for that (it is a string, use `sscanf` to read from it).

Quoting from the `man 3 getopt`:

```
   optstring is a string containing the legitimate option characters.  If such a character is followed by a colon, the option requires an argument, so getopt()
   places  a  pointer to the following text in the same argv-element, or the text of the following argv-element, in optarg.  Two colons mean an option takes an
   optional arg; if there is text in the current argv-element (i.e., in the same word as the option name itself, for example, "-oarg"), then it is returned  in
   optarg,  otherwise  optarg  is  set  to zero.  This is a GNU extension.  If optstring contains W followed by a semicolon, then -W foo is treated as the long
   option --foo.  (The -W option is reserved by POSIX.2 for implementation extensions.)  This behavior is a GNU extension, not available with libraries  before
   glibc 2.
```

If you have extra arguments (à la `cp -l file1 file2`) they are retained in `argv` on the latest positions, starting with `optind`.

PS: There's also an example at the end of the `man` page.

Comment: right, but I'm not sure how to tell getopt() to look for those args. Right now I call getopt this way: `getopt(argc, argv, "f:j:")` so I'm telling it to first look for the `-f` option and it returns the argument, then it does the same for the `-j` option. But what about if I have an additional string that also needs to be parsed that doesn't have a `-f` or `-j` specifier before it?

Comment: It will be left in the `argv` and you can read it from there. All non-matched options are left there.